# Testcafe multiple requests to endpoint synchronously not working

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Currently I am setting up testcafe and have hit a hurdle when making a request to the same endpoint.

This is an authentication request. The steps are currently:

1. Initial request is sent to server which responds with a body. This is awaited
2. Once step is retrieved from step 1 this is mutated and sent back to the server.
3. We then the same endpoint and pass in the body generated in step 2

But I am having issues in the testcafe tests as it always using the first request and returns that twice.

I have referred to this issue on testcafe https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2477 however this did not work.

```
const mock = (mockResponse, status) => {

  return RequestMock()
      .onRequestTo(/\/apitest\/authenticate\)
      .respond(mockResponse, status, {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
      });
};


const mock1 = mock(RESPONSE1, 200);
const mock2 = mock(RESPONSE2, 200);

test.requestHooks(mock1)(
  "Should redirect to error if user has been suspended after submitting",
  async t => {
    const usernameInput = Selector("#username");
    const mobileDigitOne = Selector("#mobile-digit-0");
    const mobileDigitTwo = Selector("#mobile-digit-1");
    const mobileDigitThree = Selector("#mobile-digit-2");
    const submitButton = Selector("#submit-button");

    await t
      .typeText(usernameInput, "username123456")
      .click(digits)
      .typeText(digits, "123456")
      .click(submitButton);

    await t.removeRequestHooks(mock1);

    await t.addRequestHooks(mock2);
```

Any ideas on how to request same endpoint multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish different requests to the same endpoint using the request body. You can pass different kinds of filter to the mock's `onRequestTo` method, including a predicate function. Refer to the [Filter with a Predicate](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/select-requests-to-be-handled-by-the-hook.html#filter-with-a-predicate) article for more details.

Thus, you can use a single mock for both requests, like this:

```js
function isTheSecondRequest(requestBody) {
    // This should return `true` for the mutated request body
    // and `false` for the original one.
    //
    // For example:
    return requestBody.indexOf('{ foo: bar }') !== -1;
}

const mock = RequstMock()
    .onRequestTo(request => {
        request.url === '/apitest/authenticate' &&
        !isTheSecondRequest(request.body)
    })
    .respond(RESPONSE1, 200, HEADERS)

    .onRequestTo(request => {
        request.url === '/apitest/authenticate' &&
        isTheSecondRequest(request.body)
    })
    .respond(RESPONSE2, 200, HEADERS);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response but i get the requestBody as Buffer. how do you deal with that?

Comment: Change the code to `return requestBody.toString().indexOf('{ foo: bar }') !== -1;`

Comment: I had to write logic to change response body at `respond()` rather than `onRequestTo()`. I was calling CRUD things towards the same endpoint and then loading "changed" data in SPA context.